# Restricting the scrollable area in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm trying to limit the scrollable area of a UIScrollView, but all the topics dealing with this are trying to do something other than what I want.

Basically, I have a long horizontal scrollview that fills the width of the screen. I only want the view to scroll if you put your finger on the top of the scrollview, so basically only a restricted rect area will scroll the view.

The problem is, the subviews of the scrollview swallow all the touches, so I can't check if the user's finger is inside the restricted box. I know the solution must be simple, but it is evading me at this time. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A) Just put a transparent view on the bottom half of the screen (on top of your scrollview)

B) Make your scrollView's frame smaller, but turn off clipping (`.clipsToBounds = NO`)

C) ... there are more options ,)

Comment: I tried both suggestions, and they do limit the scrollable area, but now I can't interact with the scrollview's subviews...

Comment: Then you need to write a custom view, which overwrites the 'hitTest:...' method and check, if the view from `[super hitTest:...]` is your actual scrollView, or a subview. If it is the scrollView, than you check the point and return nil, if it's not in the area where you want to have scroll.

Comment: Can you please explain more about the solution, or maybe write some simple example? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

scale your uiscrollview to the rect in which you want to be able to scroll. set `clipsToBounds` of the scroll view to `NO`.